# What happen if innodb_log_file become full?

Tags: mysql

Once innodb_log_file ib_logfile0 & ib_logfile1 got full while running big transaction,so what is mysql next action in this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

When innodb_log_file ib_logfile0 is full it start to write innodb_log_file ib_logfile1.

When this is full, it start to over with innodb_log_file ib_logfile0.

The only thing is to have enough space for both files.

The size is determined by `innodb_log_file_size=64M, but be careful mysql when you want to change the size, you need stop the server and delete the old ones. when you restart they will be created new.

Comment: The binlog is a separate issue.